# Installable Trigger Failing with Test Add-On

Tags: testing, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have been wrestling with an installable trigger issue for a couple of days now. All of my research indicates that an add-on should allow for an installable  onEdit() trigger within a spreadsheet, but my attempts keep erroring out. I have simplified my project code a bit to exemplify my issue.

The error message:

> Execution failed: Test add-on attempted to perform an action that is not allowed.

My code (listing functions is the order that they are called):

```
   function onOpen() //creates custom menu for the evaluation tool ***FOR ADMININSTRATORS ONLY***
{ 

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  if(!PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('initialized'))
  {
    ui.createMenu('Evaluation Menu') // Menu Title
      .addItem('Create Installable OnEdit Trigger', 'createInstallableOnEditTrigger')
    .addToUi();
  }
  else
  {
    ui.createMenu('Evaluation Menu') // Menu Title
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Manage Observations & Evidence')
           .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Create New Observation')
               .addItem('Formal', 'createNewFormalObservation')
               .addItem('Informal', 'createNewInformalObservation')
            )          
      .addToUi();    
  }
}


function createInstallableOnEditTrigger() { // installable trigger to create employee look-up listener when user edits the EIN fields on the Documentation Sheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEditListener')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();

  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('initialized','true');
}

function onEditListener(event) //this function conitnually listens to all edit, but only engages only certain conditions such as when a timestamp is determined to be needed or the Documentation Sheet needs to be auto-populated
{
  //Determine whether or not the conditions are correct for continuing this function
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName(); //determines the name of the currently active sheet

  if (sheetName.indexOf("Evidence") > -1) // if the active sheet is an evidence collection sheet, a timestamp may be needed
  {
    populateEvidenceTimeStamp(event, sheetName);
  }
  else if (sheetName == "Documentation Sheet") //if the active sheet is the "Documentation Sheet" than auto-population and EIN lookups may be needed
  {
    employeeLookup(event, sheetName);
  }
}
```

What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

*The below code has been added as requested by @Mogsdad.*

populateEvidenceTimeStamp() is dependent upon generateTimeStamp() which is also included below:

```
function populateEvidenceTimeStamp(event, sheetName)
{
  var evidenceColumnName = "Evidence"; 
  var timeStampColumnName = "Timestamp";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var indexOfColumnBeingEdited = actRng.getColumn();
  var indexOfRowBeingEdited = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var columnHeadersArr = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); // grabs the column headers found in the 3rd row of the evidence sheet

  var timeStampColumnIndex = columnHeadersArr[0].indexOf(timeStampColumnName); //determines the index of the Timestamp column based on its title
  var evidenceColumnIndex = columnHeadersArr[0].indexOf(evidenceColumnName); evidenceColumnIndex = evidenceColumnIndex+1; //determines the index of the evidence column based on its title
  var cell = sheet.getRange(indexOfRowBeingEdited, timeStampColumnIndex + 1); //determines the individual timestap cell that will be updated

  if (timeStampColumnIndex > -1 && indexOfRowBeingEdited > 3 && indexOfColumnBeingEdited == evidenceColumnIndex && cell.getValue() == "") // only create a timestamp if 1) the timeStampColumn exists, 2) you are not actually editing the row containing the column headers and 3) there isn't already a timestamp in the Timestamp column for that row
  {
    cell.setValue(generateTimeStamp());
  }
}

function generateTimeStamp()
{
  var timezone = "GMT-7"; // Arizona's time zone
  var timestamp_format = "MM.dd.yyyy  hh:mm:ss a"; // timestamp format based on the Java SE SimpleDateFormat class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html 
  var currTimeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);  
  return currTimeStamp;  
}
```

Below is the employeeLookup() function which is dependent upon lookupEIN()

```
function employeeLookup(event, sheetName)
{
  if(sheetName == "Documentation Sheet" && !PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('initialized')) // if the activeSheet is "Documentation Sheet" and the sheet has not yet been initialized
  {
    var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
    Logger.log("employeeLookup(): actRng: "+actRng.getRow()+" , "+actRng.getColumn());
    if(actRng.getRow() == 4 && actRng.getColumn() == 9 && event.source.getActiveRange().getValue() != "") //if the "Teacher EIN" cell is the active range and it's not empty
    { 
      var ein = actRng.getValue();
      clearDocumentationSheetTeacherProfile(); //first clear the teacher profile information to avoid the possibility of EIN/Teacher Info mismatch if previous search did not yield results
      var teacherDataArr = lookupEIN(ein, "Teachers");
      if(teacherDataArr)
      {
        //write retrieved teacher data to Documentation Spreadsheet
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Documentation Sheet");
        sheet.getRange(5, 9, 1, 1).setValue(teacherDataArr[1]); // Teacher First Name
        sheet.getRange(6, 9, 1, 1).setValue(teacherDataArr[2]); // Teacher Last Name
        sheet.getRange(7, 9, 1, 1).setValue(teacherDataArr[3]); // Teacher Email 

        sheet.getRange(11, 9, 1, 1).setValue(teacherDataArr[4]); // School Name
        sheet.getRange(11, 39, 1, 1).setValue(teacherDataArr[5]); // Site Code
        sheet.getRange(10, 30, 1, 1).setValue(calculateSchoolYear()); //School Year
      }
      else
      {
        Logger.log("employeeLookup(): type:Teachers 'died. lookupEIN() did not return a valid array'"); //alert message already sent by lookUpEIN
      }
    }
    else if (actRng.getRow() == 4 && actRng.getColumn() == 30 && actRng.getValue() != "" && !PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('initialized')) //if the "Observer EIN" cell is the active range
    {
      Logger.log("employeeLookup(): 'active range is Observer EIN'");
      var ein = actRng.getValue();
      clearDocumentationSheetObserverProfile(); //first clear the teacher profile information to avoid the possibility of EIN/Observer Info mismatch if previous search did not yield results
      var observerDataArr = lookupEIN(ein, "Observers");
      if(observerDataArr)
      {
        //write retrieved observer data to Documentation Spreadsheet
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Documentation Sheet");
        sheet.getRange(5, 30, 1, 1).setValue(observerDataArr[1]); // Observer First Name
        sheet.getRange(6, 30, 1, 1).setValue(observerDataArr[2]); // Observer Last Name
        sheet.getRange(7, 30, 1, 1).setValue(observerDataArr[3]); // Observer Email 
      }
      else
      {
        Logger.log("employeeLookup(): type:Observers 'died. lookupEIN() did not return a valid array'"); //alert message already sent by lookUpEIN
      }
    }
    else
    {
      Logger.log("employeeLookup(): 'active range is not a trigger'");
      //do nothing (not the right cell)
    }
  }
  else
  {
    //Observer log has already been initialized and documentation cannot be altered. notify user
    Logger.log("employeeLookup(): 'log already saved.... alerting user'");
    logAlreadyInitializedDialogue();
    restoreDocumentationSheetData();
  }
}

function lookupEIN(ein, type)
{
  Logger.log ("lookUpEIN(): 'engaged'");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(teacherObserverIndex_GID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(type); //lookup type aligns with the individual sheet names on the teacherObserverIndex_GID document
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var val = sheet.getDataRange();

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
  {
     if(values[i][0] == ein)
    {
      Logger.log ("lookUpEIN(): values[i]: "+values[i]);
      return values[i];
    }
    else
    { 
      Logger.log ("lookUpEIN(): 'no match found'");
    }
  }
  //a match could not be found 
  Logger.log("An EIN match could not be found"); // create a feedback pop-up
  einNotFoundDialogue(type); //alert user that there is a problem with the provided ein
}
```

Comment: 1. I think it is a simple trigger so all you need to do is name the function onEdit();

Comment: 2. If you are using the test add-on feature I had ran into issues where it would fail on the test but work when published.

Comment: What do `populateEvidenceTimeStamp` and `employeeLookup` do?

Comment: @BjornBehrendt , an earlier version of this project used a simple onEdit() instead of an installable trigger, but would throw throw following error: 
 "Execution failed: You do not have permission to perform that action. (line 136, file "Helper Functions")" The line to which it was referring was this: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(teacherObserverIndex_GID);
 I have addedd this code to my original post. It can be found in the lookupEIN function.

Comment: I have added the 'populateEvidenceTimeStamp' and 'employeeLookUp' functions to the original post, as well as the functions that they are dependent upon. @BjornBehrendt thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Triggers can't be created when running a script as Test as add-on.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/test :

> There are a number of things to keep in mind while testing add-ons:
>
> - Installable triggers are currently not supported when testing.
>   Functionality that depends on installable triggers will not be
>   testable.

Some possible workarounds

- For on open and on edit installable triggers, temporally add simple triggers to call the functions of the installable triggers. This might only work if the execution time of is less than the simple triggers limit.
- Call the functions from the installable triggers from functions that create object that emulates the corresponding event object
- Instead of using a stand-alone project use bounded projects. You might use [CLASP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) or an extension like [Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo?hl=en) to make it easier to copy the code from the stand-alone project to a bounded project.

Related

- [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451)

Comment: I'm late to the party, but a great workaround is simply to copy the onEdit code into the Script editor and work on it there instead while testing.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience onEdit() is not available for test as Add-On.

I agree the documentation is not clear, it seems to be referring to only "Installable Triggers" but I think it applies to all Triggers except for the "onInstall" trigger that is run as soon as you start the test.  (see: [Testing Google Sheet Addon Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774457/testing-google-sheet-addon-triggers) for more details)