# Appscript Time Trigger is Raising Error During Creation

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to create a time based trigger for a gmail add-on. Here is the sample code.

```
function myFunction()
{
  // do something

  // then create a time based trigger

     ScriptApp.newTrigger("dummy_fun")
    .timeBased()
    .everyHours(12)
    .create();

  //return the card
}

function dummy_fun()
{
   //do something
}
```

This is how my manifest file look like.

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Whitehorse",
  "dependencies": {},
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Time Trigger Test",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/receipt_black_24dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "myFunction"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now the trigger is created when I press run button in the app script editor. But I get following exception every time when I open/refresh the add on in my gmail account.

```
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property create on object ScriptApp.ClockTriggerBuilder. [line: 7, function: myFunction, file: Code]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this while testing the add-on? It took me a long time to realise, but setting triggers is not supported in testing add-ons. The only way to test it is manually create the trigger to check that the code works, then publishing the add-on and hope for the best.

Here's a related thread: [Google Scripts: Installable Trigger Failing with Test Add-On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721609/google-scripts-installable-trigger-failing-with-test-add-on)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks like time triggered are no longer supported in gmail add on.

Comment: It's not working anywhere, not even for editor addons.